# How to ignore/remove leading zeros?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, leading-zero

I am writing a program to add two large numbers in `C`. 
My integer array result holds the sum of  the two numbers (which were also stored in arrays).

For example, if the result array is `[0,0,3,2]` (actual array size is 20)

If 32 is my actual result, how can I display the contents of the result array without the leading zeros ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BASE 10
void align(int A[],int n);
void add(int A[],int B[], int C[]);
void Invert(int* a, int n);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char input1[20];
    char input2[20];
    int size = 20;
    int a;
    int b;
    int num1[20];
    int num2[20];
    int result[20];
    int length1 = strlen(argv[1]);
    int length2 = strlen(argv[2]);
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<length1;i++){
       input1[i] = argv[1][i];
    }
    for (i=0;i<length2;i++){
        input2[i] = argv[2][i];
    }

    a=atoi(input1);
    b=atoi(input2);
    align(num1,a);
    align(num2,b);
    add(num1,num2,result);
    Invert(result,size);
    for (i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("%d",result[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void align (int A[], int n){
    int i = 0;

    while (n) {
        A[i++] = n % BASE;

        n /= BASE;
    }

    while (i < 20) A[i++] = 0;
}

void add (int A[], int B[], int C[]) {
    int i, carry, sum;
    carry = 0;
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        sum = A[i] + B[i] + carry;
        if (sum >= BASE) {
            carry = 1;
            sum -= BASE;
        } else
            carry = 0;
        C[i] = sum;
    }

    if (carry) printf ("overflow in addition!\n");
}

void Invert(int* a, int n)
{
    int i;
    int b;
    for(i=0; i<n/2; i++){
        b = a[i];
        a[i] = a[n-i-1];
        a[n-i-1] = b;
    } 
}
```

`

Comment: Not getting..can you elaborate more?

Comment: For people here to actually understand what you are doing, it would help if you could post your code. With large numbers, I assume you mean something like big integers.

Comment: Just iterate over the numbers and only start printing them after you've seen the first non-zero? (In the special case that they are all zero, print a single 0.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, just added the code.

Comment: Yes, Rudy. I am trying to add two big integers(20 digits).

Comment: Notice that *efficient* [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) operations require *difficult* complex algorithms. So better use *existing* bignum libraries like [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/) than reinvent your own which will perform poorly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the actual digits (I assume that each digit is stored as a byte in an array of 20 bytes, lowest digit at highest index), you do something like this:

```
int i;
int size = sizeof(thearray) / sizeof(thearray[0]);

/* find first non-0 byte, starting at the highest "digit" */
for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
    if (thearray[i] != 0)
        break;

/* output every byte as character */
for (; i < size; i++)
    printf("%c", thearray[i] + '0'); /* 0 --> '0', 1 --> '1', etc. */
printf("\n");
```

Comment: +1.  Note that terminating the first loop at `size-1` would allow you to avoid the later `if else`.  Also, might be worth a note that you can only calculate `size` in the way you show if you have access to the array definition, not just a pointer to the array.

Comment: @simonc: you are right, the lowest digit can always be displayed. I'll change the code accordingly.

Comment: Actually, for C and decimal digits the disclaimer "assuming ASCII" is obsolete. C mandates that the encoding of `'0'` to `'9'` digits is consecutive.

Comment: In C, chars and bytes can both be expressed as number or as character. Adding '0' (i.e. 0x30) to 0 turns the number 0 into the character '0' (ASCII 0x30), adding it to 1 returns the character '1' (ASCII 0x31), etc. The printf format `"%c"` expects a char, not a number. Alternatively, I could have used: `printf("%d", thearray[i]);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by below code:-

```
int flag=1;
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
   if(flag==1&&array[i]!=0)
      flag=0;
   if(flag!=1)
   {
      printf("%d",array[i]);
   }
}
```

This will remove all leading zeros.

Comment: Won't this skip the first non-zero digit?

Comment: In case of 100 it will print 10

Comment: @simonc not a first non zero but first zero if zero is not leading, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution by using the pointer. The situation where only zero is stored in the array is also handled. I'm more comfortable with the pointer.

```
int test[20] = {0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0,1,2,3,4,5};
int test_bis[20] = {0};
int * ptr_test  = test_bis;

int ii = 0;

while( *(ptr_test)== 0 && ii < 20 ) {
    ptr_test++;
    ii++;
}
if( ii < 20)
    do {
        printf("%d",*(ptr_test));
        ptr_test++;

    } while (++ii < 20);
else
    printf("0");
```

Answer (score -1):

Thats for integer array you can modify it accordingly.

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    if(flag==1&&array[i]==0)
        {
               // just skips until first nonzero
        }
    else if(flag==1&&array[i]!=0){
        flag=0;               // when first nonzero comes set flag to 0 and print it
        printf("%d",array[i]);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d",array[i]);  // after first nonzero simply print it
    }
}
```