# Variable bit length in std::bitset<size>

Tags: c++, bitset, std-bitset

I'm not sure how to properly explain this, but I'm looking for a way to automatically set the `size` or `number` of the `bitset<size>` automatically

Example

```
cout << bitset<8>(7) << endl;
```

outputs with a fixed number of bits

```
0000 0111
```

I want to automatically output with variable number of bits like outputting `111` and `11001` instead of using the fixed bits.

Basically I want to cut the `0`'s in front when it's not used

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433626/variable-size-bitset

Comment: I agree with @Caramiriel, otherwise you would need to cut them off manually, in a similar manner with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839107/how-to-ignore-remove-leading-zeros).

Answer (score 3):

That's actually two questions in one. The first is how to trim the output a given bitset (i.e. remove the leading `0`'s), the second how to reduce the output to a given size.

As your interested only in the `ostream` output, for both it should be quite appropriate to use the `bitset::to_string()` conversion function, followed by an application of `string::substr`.

With this, for your example -- where it seems you want to retain `7` bits -- you would get:

```
std::cout << std::bitset<8>{}.to_string().substr(1) << std::endl;  //removes the first bit
```

You can combine that with a method to find the first set bit in order to construct the `trim` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    bitset<64> n2(n);
    cout << n2.to_string().substr(64-n2._Find_first()-1) << endl;
}
```

`std::bitset::_Find.first` will find the index of the first on bit.

We convert `n2` to a string, we then find the substring of the string from the index where we find the most significant bit subtracted by the total length - 1, therefore giving us the required result.

Testcase:

```
256
100000000
```

Comment: Note this is a non standard function of GCC